# Handling very large image files in web browsers

Tags: image-processing

First post on SO; hopefully I am doing it right :-)

Have a situation where users need to upload and view very high resolution files (they need to pan, tilt, zoom, and annotate images). A single file sometimes crosses 1 GB so loading complete file on client side is not an option.

We are thinking about letting the users upload files to the server (like everyone does), then apply some encryption on server side creating multiple, relatively small low resolution images with varying sizes. We then give users thumbnails with canvas size option on the webpage for them to pick and start their work.

Lets assume a user opens low grade image with 1280 x 1028 canvas size. Image will be broken into tiles before display, and when user clicks on a title it will be like zooming in to a specific tile. Client will send request to the server asking for higher resolution image for the title. Server will send the image which will be broken into titles again for the user to click and get another higher resolution image from server and so on ... Having multiple images with varying resolution will help us break images into tiles and serve user needs ('keep zooming in' or out using tiles).

Has anyone dealt with humongous image files? Is there a preferred technical design you can suggest? How to handle areas that have been split across tiles is bothering me a lot so not sure how above approach can be modified to address this issue.

We need to plan for 100 to 200 users connected to the website simultaneously, and ours is .NET environment if it matters

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague. I assume you are looking for hints, so here are a few:

1. I see uploading the images is a problem in the firstplace. Where I come from, upload-speeds are way slower than download speeds. (But there is litte you can do if you need your user to upload gigabytes...) Perhaps offer some more stable upload than web. FTP if you must.
2. Converting in smaller pieces should be no big problem. Use one of the availabe tools. Perhaps imagemagick. I see there is a .net wrapper out: https://magick.codeplex.com/
3. More than converting alone I think it is important not to do it everytime on the fly (you would need a realy big machine) but only once the image is uploaded. If you want to scale you can outsource this to another box in the network.
4. For the viewer. This is the interessting part. There are some ready to use ones. Google has one. It's called 'Maps' :). But there is a free alternative: OpenLayers from the OpenStreetmap Project: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers All you have to do is naming your generated files in the right way and a litte configuration.
5. Even if you must for some reasons create the tiles on the fly or can't use something like OpenLayers I would try to stick to its naming scheme. Having something working to start with is never a bad idea.

Comment: This is great info; exactly what I was looking for. Sorry I cannot vote you up it says I need a reputation of 15 or more :(

Comment: https://magick.codeplex.com/ is an newer wrapper with more functionality, would you mind changing your link?